# Adding items to a list if it's not a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, inspect

I'm trying to write a function right now, and its purpose is to go through an object's `__dict__` and add an item to a dictionary if the item is not a function. 
Here is my code:

```
def dict_into_list(self):
    result = {}
    for each_key,each_item in self.__dict__.items():
        if inspect.isfunction(each_key):
            continue
        else:
            result[each_key] = each_item
    return result
```

If I'm not mistaken, inspect.isfunction is supposed to recognize lambdas as functions as well, correct? However, if I write

```
c = some_object(3)
c.whatever = lambda x : x*3
```

then my function still includes the lambda. Can somebody explain why this is?

For example, if I have a class like this:

```
class WhateverObject:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self._value = value
    def blahblah(self):
        print('hello')
a = WhateverObject(5)
```

So if I say `print(a.__dict__)`, it should give back `{_value:5}`

Comment: Can you show an self-contained example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @Tyler function means, what you expect? Which are not function in your case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually checking if `each_key` is a function, which most likely is not. You actually have to check the value, like this

```
if inspect.isfunction(each_item):
```

You can confirm this, by including a `print`, like this

```
def dict_into_list(self):
    result = {}
    for each_key, each_item in self.__dict__.items():
        print(type(each_key), type(each_item))
        if inspect.isfunction(each_item) == False:
            result[each_key] = each_item
    return result
```

Also, you can write your code with dictionary comprehension, like this

```
def dict_into_list(self):
    return {key: value for key, value in self.__dict__.items()
            if not inspect.isfunction(value)}
```

Comment: Yes, your function is correct. However, how did you know that each key most likely not a function?

Comment: @Tyler `__dict__` will have string keys and the values are the corresponding objects.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of an easy way to find the variables of an object through the dir and callable methods of python instead of `inspect` module.

```
{var:self.var for var in dir(self) if not callable(getattr(self, var))}
```

Please note that this indeed assumes that you have not overrided `__getattr__` method of the class to do something other than getting the attributes.